# gwt page shows in internet explorer but not on chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, gwt

I am learning GWT. I created a basic GWT page (its a vertical panel with coupla widgets and lines on it). Interestingly it shows up fine on IE11, but shows up only partially on Chrome or Firefox. The worst part is when I try to access it from an iPad (Safari and Chrome), nothing shows up at all. This is the [link] (http://www.teachastronomy.com/home_gwt.aspx) to the page.  I searched through stackoverflow, but everyone seems to be having the problem otherway round, i.e shows up in chrome but not in IE.Has anyone faced this before or know what could I be doing wrong?

Extra info, just in case it helps: my ultimate aim is to switch the flash page to a gwt based page.

Comment: I don't see anything related to GWT on this page. BTW, there's an `<object>` (why not using an `<iframe>` ?!) that tries to load a page on another port, and it doesn't load.

Comment: The actual gwt page is here [link] (teachastronomy.com:8082/v45/V31_gwt_teach_astro.html) hosted on an apache tomcat.  Now this gwt page opens up in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome. Basically What am asked to do is to embed it inside another aspxpage (which was the link I had posted earlier). So I created an html output from gwt and embedded it in the aspx page as an object. Is it wrong? Mithun Paul

Answer (score 0):

Closing this. As suggested by Thomas Broyer I just replaced the Gwt Object with an iFrame. I was calling it from tomcat, hence the same origin policy was hitting me in the background. Instead now I ported everything to IIS and things are working fine.